# C++ Constructors Runtime/Compile Time

Tags: c++, dynamic, constructor, runtime, compile-time

As I know we can create objects in runtime or in compile-time. For example

```
SomeType object1;
SomeType *object2 = new SomeType;
```

So I think that in the code here;

```
int main(){

    cout << "lalalal";
    SomeType object1;
}
```

A constructor should be called for object1 and then lalalal should appear at screen. Because compiler is allocating the memory before the program starts. So at what point I'm wrong?

Comment: All objects are created at runtime. The location and semantics of it are what change.

Comment: Memory allocation for an object and construction of that object are two different things, and can occur in separate steps.  When the memory allocation happens for a function local object is indeterminant, as far as the standard is concerned, but the object's construction happens at the point in the program where you declare it (at runtime).

Comment: @chris: Objects with `constexpr` constructors and `constexpr` arguments _can_ be created at compile-time

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Not totally independent.  Memory allocation must occur before the object is constructed.

Comment: @K-ballo, That's a good point. I forgot about that, but it's very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I know we can create objects in runtime or in compile-time.

Not really.  In your code example, the first object is created with *automatic* storage duration (often described as "on the stack"), and the second with <s>*allocated*</s> *dynamic* storage duration (often described as "on the heap").  But these both happen at runtime.

> A constructor should be called for object1 and then lalalal should appear at screen.

Statements in functions are executed from top-to-bottom (not including loops, obviously).  So the object is created second.<sup>*</sup>

> Because compiler is allocating the memory before the program starts.

Yes, it's possible that the memory is allocated ahead of time.  But as far as *observable* effects are concerned, that's irrelevant.

---

<sub>* However, as you haven't included a newline character in your string, what you *may* be seeing is the effect of line-buffering; on many systems, output isn't displayed until newline characters are received, or until the program terminates.</sub>

Comment: It's not _allocated_ storage duration, but _dynamic_ storage duration.  And storage duration is not necessarily the same as object lifetime.  In this case, the compiler _can_ extend the storage duration of `object1` as much as it wants, but the object lifetime must start at the definition, and end when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: And I don't understand your note.  C++ doesn't have the concept of line buffered, so newlines in the output have absolutely no effect on when data is flushed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: oh, maybe the terminology has changed between C and C++.  And yes, you may be correct about iostreams. (This is very much a C answer ;)). An edit may occur shortly...

Comment: The C standard only talks about _automatic_ and _static_ storage duration, which make one wonder what the storage duration of an object created with `malloc` is.  C++ talks about _automatic_, _static_ and _dynamic_ storage duration (which makes one wonder about the storage duration of temporaries or exceptions).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ok, you're right about the terminology (but note that C99 6.2.4 says "*There are three storage
durations: static, automatic, and allocated.*")  But a quick test has demonstrated that line-buffering can still apply to C++ iostreams.

Comment: No.  There is no such thing as line buffering in C++.  Nor unbuffered (at least conceptually---if you have a buffer size of 0, the stream is effectively unbuffered).  A stream can be `unitbuffer`ed or not, but that's all.  (`std::cerr` is `unitbuffer`ed by default.)  Unit buffering means that each call to `<<` will result in a flush.  But if you output something like `"abc\nxyz"`, there will be no flush at the `'\n'`.  And finally, of course, if you use `std::endl`, the semantics are to output a `'\n'` and then flush the stream.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, I don't know about any of that (but I should probably look into it!).  But a test along the lines of `cout << "a"; sleep(1); cout << "b\nc"; sleep(1); cout << "d\n";` running under a Bash shell behaved as I would "expect".  Maybe "line buffering" is the wrong term, but that's certainly what it behaves like!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Just because the standard does not mention a concept (line-buffering), does not mean that thing does not occur in implementations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What do you "expect"?  Line buffering would give a one second pause, then "ab\n", then a one second pause, then "cd\n".  The standard requires "a", a one second pause, then "b\nc", a one second pause, then "c" (at least on `std::cerr`---`std::cout` should not be unitbuffered).  Perhaps you are observing a side effect of `sync_with_stdio` being true?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The standard makes some very concrete requirements. In particular, that `rdbuf()->sputc()` only invoke `overflow()` if there is no room in the buffer.  Which means, basically, that an implementation that line buffers, per se, isn't conform.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth (and @BenjaminLindley) The standard is very vague about `sync_with_stdio`.  One possible implementation is to use a special `streambuf` which just forwards to the stdio functions; this would result in line buffering on `cout` (provided there is no buffering in this special `streambuf`, but if there were, I don't know how you could effectively synchronize).  Another possibility would be to use a special flag in the `ostream::sentry` object, which would flush the stdio object in the constructor, and the `streambuf` in the destructor.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Finally, a quick test on my side.  I only have access to Windows here: trying your sequence in a standard console window results in what I would expect: "a", a pause, then "b\nc", another pause, then "d\n".  executing the same binary under CygWin bash results in a long pause, then all of the characters appearing at one.  So either bash or (more likely) the minwin Window is doing some buffering.  And we can conclude that there is an additional player, the display device, in the equation.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I get pause, then "ab\n", then pause, then "cd\n".  I don't have access to the machine I was running on right now, but I'm definitely going to look into this more...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It's worth trying it with `std::cerr` as well.  `cerr` is required to be unit buffered, where as `cout` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are two separate concepts in C++: storage duration,
and object lifetime.  And while the storage duration cannot be
shorter than the object lifetime, the reverse is not necessarily
true.  And second, both are runtime concepts, not compile time.

In this case, however, there is no real difference.  Both the
storage duration and the lifetime of the object `object1` start
when the definition is executed, and end when it goes out of
scope.  Most compiler will, in fact, allocate all of the memory
for local variables at the top of the function, but only because
there is no way a conforming program can tell that it wasn't
allocated at the definition.  Anything which affects the
observable behavior of the program, however, must occur when the
standard says it should occur.

Answer (score 0):

No, `object1` in your example is not 'created' at compile time, it is created in runtime just like the other object. Moreover, `object1` is 'constructed' after the `cout` command is executed, and therefore the constructor of it is executed afterwards. The memory for it might have been allocated before that though.